# Not able to get GUI on Windows 11 when trying to access Ubuntu PC through SSH

Tags: ssh

I installed ssh on a remote Ubuntu PC and want to access its GUI from my local Windows 11 PC.

I read that to display the GUI, I will have to to do this:

```
ssh -X username@ip_add
```

I also tried the above command with `-Y` tag

I did the same thing on my local PC, but getting this error:

```
Error: Can't open display:
```

When I do:

```
export DISPLAY=:1
```

I get the GUI on the remote PC as expected,
but not able to get the display on local PC even after doing:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyError: Can't open display: :0.0
```

and got the above error

What can I do to get the GUI on my local Windows PC?

Comment: Did you check if the remote machine is accepting X11?

on the receiving end, you would have to have the following parameter in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:
`X11Forwarding yes`

Comment: @CyrilChaboisseau it is set to "yes". I mean it is accepting X11

Comment: Do you have a X11 implementation installed on your Windows in order to launch remote graphic application locally? Usually this is done with the installation of xlaunch from the Cygwin package